# Initialize and bind swift optional member at the same time?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-binding

My class contains optional member properties like this:

```
class PauseRenderTarget: RenderTarget {
    var background: SKShapeNode? = nil
    var resume: Entity?
    var restart: Entity?
    var reset: Entity?

    func createEntities()
}
```

When I initialize and want to use these variables, I end up having to do something like this:

```
func createEntities() {
    self.resume = EntityMaker.MakeResumeEntity()
    if let resume = self.resume {
        EntityManager.add(resume)
    }
}
```

Is there a way in swift to combine these two operations?

Comment: Is the second piece of code inside your `PauseRenderTarget`?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just move the code inside the `didSet` of `resume`.

```
var resume: Entity? {
    didSet {
        if let resume = self.resume {
            EntityManager.add(resume)
        }
    }
}
```